# How to fix my elseif statement?

Tags: php

I have an elseif statement, I'm confuse why is not working?

This my script

```
 if(isset($namasupexp))
      {
        $supexp = $namasupexp;  //condition 1
        echo $supexp;
      }
 elseif(isset($namasupexp2))
      {
        $supexp = $namasupexp2; //condition 2 is not work, or ignore
        echo $supexp;
      }//end if
```

Why Only in condition1 is work, and other condition not work?

Can anyone tell me the solution or my misatake?

I really appreciate your answer. Thanks

Comment: More information is needed.  What's in these variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($namasupexp))
{
    // if this check is satisfied, it will stop checking any else/elseif statements after it
}
elseif(isset($namasupexp2))
{

}//end if
```

If you want both to be checked do,

```
if(isset($namasupexp))
{
}

if(isset($namasupexp2))
{

}
```

Comment: I have try it your advice, but now, the condition one is not working? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the flow comes into condition 1, then it will never come into condition 2.

In your case, don't use elseif.

```
 if(isset($namasupexp)) {
   $supexp = $namasupexp;  //condition 1
   echo $supexp;
 }
 if(isset($namasupexp2)) {
   $supexp = $namasupexp2; //condition 2 
   echo $supexp;
 }
```

Comment: I have try you advice,but now, the condition one is not working? any idea?

Comment: actually this script is long. The condition is from the 2 selection. So if user chose first selection, isset will be catch it, and if user coohse the another, or second selectio, isset will catch it and run the condition 2. In case, now the condition 2 is work, but if I try the first selection, the value is NULL.

Comment: @Septiyo Code never lies, if it does not come into condition 1, then `isset($namasupexp)` must be false.

Comment: I really Thanks for your advice, it still not work, but I have new idea, i combine have combine the selection, so I have avoid the if statement., thaks so much ^_^